# You are the best mom anyone could ever had/have

Tags: grammar, word-usage, word-choice

Which of these is better?

> You are the best mom anyone could ever have.
>
> You are the best mom anyone could ever had.

I am a bit confused with these and if they are in a different tense then kindly elaborate that too.
And if it wrong in any other way, please mention what.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

"could" is a modal verb, and it requires a short infinitive after it.

So it is correct to say:

> You are the best mom **anyone** could ever **have**.

---

I think it is more *usual* to say:

> You are the best ... anyone could **wish for**.

or

> You are the best ... anyone could **ask for**.

Comment: to add, you can say that the second one should be **You are the best mom anyone has ever had**

Comment: that is correct also, but the meaning is different

Comment: Your explanation about what's correct is right, certainly. I think what's more usual depends heavily on dialect.